# How can I get JSON data when the value is a JSON value with swiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swifty-json

I'm using swiftyJSON in my iOS project but I have some trouble to get some data in my valid JSON...

```
whoJson:

[
  {
    "name": "[{\"code\":\"en\",\"name\":\"John\"},{\"code\":\"fr\",\"name\":\"Jacques\"}]",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "[{\"code\":\"en\",\"name\":\"Bob\"},{\"code\":\"fr\",\"name\":\"Robert\"}]",
    "id": 11
  }
]
```

With this code:

```
println(who[0]["name"])
```

The result is:

```
[{"code":"en","name":"John"},{"code":"fr","name":"Jacques"}]
```

How can I get John or Jacques values?
I tried this but it doesn't work...

```
println(who[0]["name"][0]["name"])
```

Comment: You have what is correctly termed "embedded JSON".  It must be run through the JSON parser a second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `name` is itself a JSON string.

Convert the string into an `NSData` instance (using the correct string encoding - I only use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` here as an example since it generally works for most cases):

**Swift**:

```
var name : NSString = who[0]["name"] as! NSString
var nameAsData : NSData? = name.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

**Objective-C:**

```c
NSString *name = who[0][@"name"];
NSData *nameAsData = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then turn that data into a JSON object (an array in this case) using this:

**Swift:**

```
var error : NSError?
var names : NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nameAsData!, options: nil, error: &error) as! NSArray;
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog("Error reading JSON: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```c
NSError *__autoreleasing error;
NSArray *names = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:nameAsData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading JSON: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

So now, unless there was an error parsing the JSON in `nameAsData`, `names` should be an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects. You can then do whatever you want with it – for example, to get "John" or "Jacques" you would do this:

**Swift:**

```
NSLog("first name: %@", names[0]["name"] as! NSString) // John
NSLog("second name: %@", names[1]["name"] as! NSString) // Jacques
```

**Objective-C:**

```c
NSLog(@"first name: %@", names[0][@"name"]); // John
NSLog(@"second name: %@", names[1][@"name"]); // Jacques
```